# Parallelize Dataset Query: What is the best way to change Query "compilation"?

Tags: parallelization, dataset, map, query

As per Mathematica [Query documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html):

> Before being applied, Query expressions are "compiled" into ordinary
> compositions of ordinary Wolfram Language functions and their operator
> forms. To see the compiled form of a Query, use Normal:
>
> ```
> In[3]:= Query[All, f] // Normal
> Out[3]= Map[f]
> ```

Sadly, Query translates to Map, no matter how big the dataset and no matter how many Kernels we have available. Ideally there should be ParallelQuery function that worked like this:

```
 In[3]:= PQuery[All, f] // Normal
 Out[3]= ParallelMap[f]
```

To that end I have created my own `PQuery` function:

```
PQuery[d_, q__] := If[Head@d === Dataset, Dataset, # &]@
  Replace[Normal@Query@q, Map[f_] :> ParallelMap[f, Normal@d]]
```

The idea is to let `Query` be "compiled" and then replace the topost `Map` with a `ParallelMap`. Also, I remove any wrapper like `Dataset` around the data, since `ParallelMap` doesn't seem to like `Dataset` as parameter.

My questions are:

- Is there any simpler and/or more robust way of doing this (this breaks for example if the head is e.g. `MapAt`)?
- Also, something seems to be extremely slow for some kinds of datasets (could this be caused by `Normal`?)

Comment: Can you show an example of usage for your `PQuery` function, and a toy dataset as well? As this stands, it is somewhat unclear to me what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @MarcoB Sorry for the extremely late reply. The idea is very simple: `Query[All,f][Dataset[{1,2}]` essentially maps `f` over `{1,2}`. Now, if `f` takes a long time, it would be good if the `Map` (you can see this `Map` by evaluating `Normal@Query[All,f]`) could be replaced by a `ParallelMap` (at least the topmost instance). The approach used for `PQuery` is a very primitive implementation of this idea, and also rather slow (as mentionned).